# I have a 404 in Ask Ubuntu

Tags: discussion

What can I do, have I done something broken? Have I destroyed the site?

**o_O**

How should I proceed?

[image]

Comment: You're not being serious here, right?

Comment: @kos Hmmm, … No =)

Comment: I don't know why but I've kinda suspected it. :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a real question

Comment: @kos: [SOHF](http://gaarde.org/acronyms/?lookup=SOHF)?  **That's serious!  a 404 in the review queue!**  *We're all going to die!*  **:D**

Comment: Based on the rep score and badge count, that's not a recent screenshot. But +1 anyway.    :)

Answer (score 6):

As long as it's not a [403](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403), or a [418](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_418), I think it's fine!

Comment: And it would have been nice if the 404 was because of an empty queue

Comment: +1 for the HTCPCP!

Comment: wow, 418, great =)

Comment: There is a good list of em here: [HTTP Status Cats](https://www.flickr.com/photos/girliemac/sets/72157628409467125)